# Laravel Multiple Filters Table with Multiple Collections

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a multiple filter function to filter my table. I have a model called Product and it has collections named categories, colors and sizes. I have the following in my view:

```
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group mt-3">
                        <label>{{ __('Categories') }}</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="select-categories">
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group mt-3">
                        <label>{{ __('Colors') }}</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="select-colors">
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                            @foreach($colors as $color)
                            <option value="{{ $color->id }}">{{ $color->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group mt-3">
                        <label>{{ __('Sizes') }}</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="select-sizes">
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                            @foreach($sizes as $size)
                            <option value="{{ $size->id }}">{{ $size->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And then I use JQuery to send a AJAX request to my controller with the current selected option values of all three dropdowns.

Example data:
Categories: All
Colors: Red
Sizes: Small

Now I wish to show the products with the color red and size small but the category doesn't matter. 
I get the collections with the use of one to many relationships and link tables.

```
$product->categories
$product->colors
$product->sizes
```

I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: what you want actually?

Comment: If you are displaying all products data in a table from a method i-e index method lets say, then you need to place these dropdowns on that same page above the table, and you need to use same index method with same route and with same action `GET`, that will be easy for you.

Comment: @user11622164 Example data: Categories: All Colors: Red Sizes: Small

Now I wish to show the products with the color red and size small but the category doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to below:

```
public function index(ProductRequest $request) 
{
   $query = Product::where($request->validated());

   return ProductResource::collection($query);
}
```

and in your ProductRequest you can define filters that you want to allow

```
class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
   ...
   public function rules()
   {
      return [
         'categories' => 'exists:categories,id'
         ....
      ];
   }
```